# How to show a slow transition of a canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have written a canvas within  and when I click a link, I am expecting the canvas to reduce to a smaller size. I am able to achieve this using onClick event but I want to show the slow transition from larger to smaller size. Could anyone throw some pointers please?

Comment: Here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: Do you intend the canvas element itself to shrink or for the content drawn to the canvas to shrink?

Answer (score 0):

jquery .animate() function can do the trick:

```
div.onClick(function(){
 $(this).animate(height:'10px',2000);
});
```

Comment: When you resize the canvas element with CSS, be sure you maintain the current aspect ratio or else the content will appear distorted. Do this by changing the CSS width & height by the same percentage.

Comment: Thats right @markE . yet if the element is using only single color , no distortion will occur.